# Setup an htacces file with 2 different redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have got a domain called www.domain.nl
I want to redirect www.domain.nl to newdomain.com/new
all other urls from domain.nl for example www.domain.nl/old/  should redirect to www.newdomain.com/old/

and of course I want google to preserve my ranking (301)

Can anyone tell me what my htaccess file looks like.

thanks

Comment: `RedirectPermanent / http://www.newdomain.com/old`?

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://newdomain.com/new [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} domain.nl
RewriteRule ^$ http://newdomain.com/ [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} domain.nl
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/old$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

(Untested)